# Can I use two themes at once in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, vscode-extensions

I would like to define a theme that covers some niche scopes and/or highlights some specific scopes, and then use it alongside any existing mainstream theme. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can always only set one theme. The only option you have is to add custom styles to your settings, as described in the first paragraph on the [Theme Color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) page.